# How do I subset a named range in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel

I have a named range in excel, of one column and 40 rows. I would like to take the product of the last 36 elements of that column vector. I cannot get index or offset to work. I would think this would do it, but I get a reference error:

```
=PRODUCT(OFFSET(NamedRange,4,0,36,0))
```

I can index the 4th element, and the 36th element:

```
=INDEX(NamedRange,4)
=INDEX(NamedRange,36)
```

If excel was even kind of intuitive, I would use this:

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(NamedRange,4:36))
```

But this does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(NamedRange,4):INDEX(NamedRange,40))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `=PRODUCT(INDEX(NamedRange,4):INDEX(NamedRange,40))` however `=PRODUCT(OFFSET(NamedRange,3,0,36,1))` should also work